# MYSQL request from two tables, in order to display a table

Tags: mysql

I have got a MySQL database, managed with phpMyAdmin.

I am not very clever at MySQL requests.

In **table1** are (among others) the 2 following columns :

**- id_product**

**- active**

In **table2** are (among others) the 2 following columns :

**- id_product**

**- description**

I **would like to write a request** that display a table as follows :

- having, at least, the **id_product column** and the **description column**
- and having only **product** for which the **active** field is equal to 1 (the active field can only have a value of 0 or 1)

Thank you in advance for any help in this matter.

Patrick

Comment: I don't see a question here. What problem are you having? This is a very simple join.  Have you done any research or made an attempt at writing a query to satisfy your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You want to make an Inner Join between the tables.  This matches rows from one table to rows in another, excluding rows that don't have a match.  Then you want to add a restriction to only return those with active = 1.

This looks like:

```
 Select t2.id_product, t2.description from table2 t2 
            inner join table1 t1 
                    on t1.id_product = t2.id_product
            where t1.active = 1;
```